# How can I invoke a command on the ViewModel on SelectionChanged of a ListView?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm, command

In a MVVM/WPF environment, I want to invoke a command (`ComputeCommand`) on the ViewModel when the `SelectionChanged` event of a ListView is raised. How can this be done, either in XAML or in C#?

Here is my command class. I have tried `MainViewModel.Instance.MyCommand.Execute();` in the codebehind, but it's doesn't accept that.

```
public class ComputeCommand : ICommand
{
    public ComputeCommand(Action updateReport)
    {
        _executeMethod = updateReport;
    }

    Action _executeMethod;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _executeMethod.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really recommend the use of a Mvvm framework like [MVVM Light](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/), so you can do something like this:

XAML:

```
xmlns:MvvmLight_Command="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras"
xmlns:Custom="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;  assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"

 <ListBox>
 ...
     <Custom:Interaction.Triggers>
          <Custom:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged ">
             <MvvmLight_Command:EventToCommand PassEventArgsToCommand="False" Command="{Binding Path=ComputeCommand}"/>
          </Custom:EventTrigger>
     </Custom:Interaction.Triggers>

</Listbox>
```

ViewModel:

```
public RelayCommand ComputeCommand{ get; private set; }
```

This is IMO an elegant way to keep your events wiring clean and tidy.

Answer (score 2):

To answwer your question - you are missing a parameter. THis call should work:

```
MainViewModel.Instance.MyCommand.Execute(null);
```

However, you dont need an ICommand for that, this interface serves different purpose.

What you need is to either handle SelectionChanged on view side

```
var vm = DataContext as YourViewModelType;
if (vm != null)
{
    vm.Compute(); //some public method, declared in your viewmodel
}
```

or to handle it on viewmodel side by binding to IsSelected property of item container

Comment: I have tried bothe of solutions but none worked :/ I'm using MVVM because I have some data to be update on the screen at the moment of the execution

Comment: What do you mean by "none worked"?  They failed to compile? Failed to execute? With exception? Or what?

Comment: You cant bind event to an ICommand. You should replace it with SelectionChanged="SelectionChangedHandler" and then implement this handler in code behind the way i described above

Answer (score 1):

In general: To invoke a command when an event of a control is raised, you can use EventTriggers.

```
<ListView>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged" >
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CommandToBindTo}" CommandParameter="{Binding CommandParameterToBindTo}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ListView>
```

To do this, you need to reference *System.Windows.Interactivity.dll* in your XAML:

`xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"`

That being said, you should use a MVMM framework, for example MVVM to simplify the implementation of commands in general. It is not maintainable in the long run to have a single class for every command you need. A framework like MVVMLight or PRISM provides `DelegateCommands` which allow you to create new commands from delegates (methods on your ViewModel) directly.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to define a binding for `Command`, so the function that have to be 
executed on the invokation of the command.

This *can* be done in XAML, like:

```
<CommandBinding Command="name_of_the_namespace:ComputeCommand" Executed="ComputeCommandHandler" />
```

After, you can, for example in some class initialize a command, like:

```
 public class AppCommands {
    public static readonly ICommand ComputeCommand = 
             new   RoutedCommand("ComputeCommand", typeof(AppCommands));
 }
```

and after can use it like:

```
 AppCommands.ComputeCommand.Execute(sender);
```

When you're dealing with `WPF`, so `MVVM` pattern, you need to write the much more code the usual, but benefit from flexibility of it.

Comment: And where to add the <CommandBinding .../> ?? anywhere or inside <Window.Resources> ?